# Spotify Android SDK Authentication Error

Tags: android, spotify

The last couple of days I've been trying out the Spotify SDK for Android. I have coded a simple app that has been working pretty well. However, today the Spotify Authentication started giving me an error. I can't really tell what's wrong as I can't find an error code to look up. Note that I'm not very familiar with APIs in general.

This is the code on my `onCreate()`

```
AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = 
             new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(SpotifyAPI.CLIENT_ID, 
                      AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, 
                      SpotifyAPI.REDIRECT_URI);

builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming", "user-library-read"});
AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);

Log.d("login", "login attempted");
```

And this is the `onResult()`

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    Log.d("login", "login result");
    AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

    switch (response.getType()) {
        // Response was successful and contains auth token
        case TOKEN:
            SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();

            api.setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());
            SpotifyAPI.getInstance().setSpotifyService(api.getService());
            Log.d("login", "logged in");
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            break;

        // Auth flow returned an error
        case ERROR:
            Log.d("login", "login error");
            break;
```

The `ERROR` case is called all of a sudden. It's also interesting to note that while the Authentication returns an error on my phone, on a virtual device it just doesn't ever return a result. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: response.getError() returns you the error

Comment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, code: -2, failing url: